# Can someone explain the function of the third parameter of "add_rewrite_tag"

Tags: rewrite-rules

Can you please explain the third function parameter `queryreplace` of [`add_rewrite_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag).

Explanation with code examples will be much appreciated.

*UPDATE*

i wrote this code below to make a page with slug `your-profile` to display the profile info of a user with the url `example.com/profile/user-name`

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {

add_rewrite_tag('%who%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^profile/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=your-profile&who=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

I then capture the username like so:

```
$who = (get_query_var('who')) ? get_query_var('who') : 0;
    if($who){
        $user = get_user_by('login', $who);

        print_r($user);
    }
```

The code above work fine. what is the use of the `%who%` since am i won't be using in WP permaling settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter tells WordPress what *query variable(s)* to use/match.

We can query our WordPress database with those public query variables, via requests like `example.com/?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2` but we usually want to rewrite it to something more pretty, like `example.com/bar1/bar2/`.

In the Codex [there's a list](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars)  of the default available public query variables:

```
attachment
attachment_id
author
author_name
cat
category_name
comments_popup
day
error
feed
hour
m
minute
monthnum
name
p
page_id
paged
pagename
post_parent
post_type
preview
second
static
subpost
subpost_id
tag
tag_id
tb
w
year
```

### Example 1:

If we create a custom taxonomy, called for example `country`, then we will automatically get:

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%country%', '([^/]+)', 'country=' );
```

where the third parameter is the *query variable* that must end with `=`.

### Example 2:

If we want to use the permalink structure `example.com/article-1984` for the `post` post type only, then we can introduce the custom rewrite tag `%article-pid%`:

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    add_rewrite_tag( '%article-pid%', 'article-([0-9]+)', 'p=' );
});
```

Notice that here the query variable is `p` and it must end with `=`.

The request `example.com/article-1984` is therefore interpret as `example.com/?p=1984`, after we flush the rewrite rules, for example by re-saving the permalinks settings.

Then we have to modify the output of the `get_permalink()` function accordingly:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', function( $post_link, $post ) {
    return str_replace( '%article-pid%', 'article-' . $post->ID, $post_link );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Here's how the permalink settings would look like in this case:

[image: %article-pid%]

If we would use `article-%post_id%` instead, then it seems to mess up the rewrite rules for the other custom post types and taxonomies.

Comment: My question now is, from `example 1` what's the usefulness of the **query variable** `country=`? same goes for the `p=` in *example 2*

Comment: In example 2 the request `example.com/article-1984` is interpret as `example.com/?p=1984`. You will have to tell WordPress what *query variable* to use ([here's a list of most of them](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars)). You can also define your own.

Comment: i have updated the question. can you please also give me an answer?

Thanks for going out of your way to help me.

Comment: As far as I understand your setup, you don't need `add_rewrite_tag`, just stick to your `add_rewrite_rule` part.

Comment: but without the `add_rewrite_tag`, `get_query_var()` won't be able to recognize the `who` query var.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that ;-) Well you could use for example the [`query_vars`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) filter to add it.